# Avoid inserting duplicates in binary search tree

Tags: c++, insert, binary-search-tree

So I have an binary search tree that works perfectly except for that fact that I don't want to insert duplicates. I've tried thinking over a few ways to do this but can't seem to figure it out.

What I'm trying to do is call my search method first before inserting anything to check and if it isn't there then have the insert method insert the course.

Does anyone know a good way to approach this? Is my logic correct?

Here's my insert method:

```
bool BinarySearchTree::treeInsert(string courseNumber, string courseTitle)
 {
Course * z = new Course(courseNumber, courseTitle);
Course *x, *y;
y = NULL;
x = root;

while (x != NULL){
    y = x;
    if(z->getCourseNumber() < y->getCourseNumber()){
        x = x->getLeft();
    } else{
        x = x->getRight();
    }
}
z->setParent(y);

if (y == NULL){
    root = z;
} else if (z->getCourseNumber() < y->getCourseNumber()){
        y->setLeft(z);
    }
    else {
        y->setRight(z);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: One issue is that tou allocate for a new `Course` before you know you will ever need it.  If a duplicate is found, you have a memory leak.

Comment: Free clue: what happens "if(z->getCourseNumber() == y->getCourseNumber())" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose to check for equality in the loop instead of following the chain of `>=`,  and return false if no insertion takes place.  The creation of the new element would be created only if certain that it'll be used:

```
 bool BinarySearchTree::treeInsert(string courseNumber, string courseTitle)
 {
     Course *x=root, *y=nullptr;

     while (x != NULL) {
         y = x;
         if(courseNumber < y->getCourseNumber())
             x = x->getLeft();
         else if(courseNumber==y->getCourseNumber()) 
             return false;
         else x = x->getRight();
     }
     Course * z = new Course(courseNumber, courseTitle);
     z->setParent(y);
     if (y == NULL)
         root = z;
     else if (z->getCourseNumber() < y->getCourseNumber())
            y->setLeft(z);
     else   y->setRight(z);
     return true; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your insert method at the end of the loop, when you are trying to insert a duplicate, the course number in `y` will be equal to the course number in `z`. If that is the case, don't do anything (except delete `z`as you currently allocated it even if you don't need it).

Comment: The allocation for the new object shouldn't be done until there is confirmation that there is no duplicate.  It may not be wrong, but it sure is wasteful to allocate a brand new object for no reason.   The only thing needed to search is the course number, not an entire object.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I agree, I just didn't put it in as you had already said it in the comments.

Comment: Although we can't tell if `courseNumber`the string can be compared with `getCourseNumber`the member function.